# access a column that can have different names

Tags: r

I am writing a function to automatically read in columns of several data frames. The name and the position of the column that I want to access differs sometimes

as a reproducable example:

```
a= c(1:3)
b= c(4:6)
A = data.frame(a,b)
colnames(A) = c("column1", "column2")

B = data.frame(b,a)
colnames(B) = c("col1", "col2")
```

Now I want to access the values a, something like:

```
`$`(A, "column1"|"col2")
```

Because logical operators don't work for characters, so I tried to go with

```
A[,which(colnames(A[,1]) == "column1" | names(A[,2]) =="col2")]
```

but it seems that the colnames()-function doesn't work that.
Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Comment: You need to use the `A[,"colname"]` way of referencing columns, rather than `A$colname`.

Comment: Are the names of the columns rougly the same? Then you could do something like this: `select(A, matches(".col."))`

Comment: Have you tried `grep("column1|col2", names(A))` to get the column indices?

Comment: I usually use brackets, I thought it looked easier to read the other way, and I only wanted to show what exactly I am looking for (as it might be a bit confusing with the columns)

Comment: @RuiBarradas this is exactly what i needed. Shame I didn't think of it myself. If you post it as an answer, I will accept

Comment: @Eddyvonb the columns are in different languages. But I'll keep matches in the back of my mind, haven't worked with it yet

Comment: `c( which( colnames( A ) == "column1" ), which( colnames( B ) == "col2" ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `grep`. It works with both `A` and `B`.

```
A[, grep("column1|col2", names(A))]
#[1] 1 2 3

B[, grep("column1|col2", names(B))]
#[1] 1 2 3
```